# Cracked block - replace just the block

Tags: engine, gasoline, gm, block

I have a GM 350/5.7 marine petrol engine. The block has a large crack due to freezing. The engine itself doesn't have that many hours on it, so the other parts should be quite OK.

Is it possible to change just the block? Move all the valves, pistons, head, crank etc from the old block?

Does the new block need to machined?

Comment: Have you thought about getting the aluminum block welded?

Comment: It's cast iron, but welding is one possibility. But i would rather get a new block.

Comment: The cost of competent labor likely makes a replacement engine a little less costly. Welding cast iron is risky ; even if inspection shows it is not cracked after welding , it is a significant possibility in the future. I think you need a "short block" ; a complete block without heads, manifolds, etc.

Comment: The problem is this engine is reverse rotation and has therefore (and because of the marine application) a peculiar crankshaft.

Comment: Welding a cast iron block **is** possible. And did it once for a v8 that had frost damage - worked fine for years... If you are not a good welder though...

Comment: A good welder can repair the crack, they make special nickel welding rod for just that, welding cast iron.

Comment: The potential problem is that the nickel alloyed with iron and carbon leaves areas of retained austenite that can later transform to hard , brittle martensite.

Comment: These don't really answer the question, is it possible to reuse the old crank, pistons, valves etc with a new block? Does the block need to be bored / honed?